# Elasticsearch mapping for TShark

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, wireshark, packet, tshark

In February 15 this year, TShark added support to generate a mapping file for Elasticsearch with the option `-G elastic-mapping`. The thing is that I have tried that but Elasticsearch complains when you try to `PUT` the generated mapping. Any ideas? (I am using Elasticsearch version 7.4).

Answer (score 1):

The generated mapping file with the `-G elastic-mapping` option is compatible with Elasticsearch version previous to 5.X **only**.
Here (https://www.wireshark.org/news/20190215.html) you can see that they added this support to generate the mapping, however it was already for an old version at that time.
Remember that since the mapping file can be huge, protocols can be selected by using the option `--elastic-mapping-filter`. For example:

```
tshark -G elastic-mapping --elastic-mapping-filter ip,udp,dns
```

Once you have generated the mapping you should modify it for the newer versions. For example the structure of the JSON has already changed and Elasticsearch will complain about it. just remove the `pcap_file` attribute as the first thing.
Then, you will also need to change the `string` types as they were [removed since version 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings). Change them for `keyword` type.

There might be other things to change but these are the main ones. After that just `PUT` the template and you can start ingesting data from TShark.